# Automatic community detection / Aid to find the right community

Tags: feature-request

There is a growing number of Stack Exchange communities. It happened a few times, that I was not sure, to which community my question suited the best and it also happened, that I totally forgot about a community and I asked a question in the wrong one.

For example I asked a Raspberry Pi question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), although there is a Raspberry Pi community.

I think it's possible to detect from the title and the tags, to which community a question suits the best. If it's the case, that the user is about to post a question on the wrong community, a hint could be displayed.

Another idea to approach this problem is to implement something like a wizard. I imagine this like a text field, where you can enter tags. Then the most suitable community appears.

Comment: We already have [something](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) better in place though. A question with the "biochemistry" tag may either fir Chem or Biology.SE and nothing other than a regular can tell you where to go.

Comment: We do have [tag:site-recommendation] for questions about where a question could be asked...

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about this. Maybe it's possible to make the work-flow easier for the user, to find the right site.